# Make image fill the container in flexbox

Tags: css

How can I make an image fill the full height in a flexbox item? The image should be stretched to fill the height while keeping the aspect ratio.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.banner-message {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.banner-message .banner-message-media {
  flex: 1;
}
.banner-message .banner-message-content {
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-message">
  <div class="banner-message-media">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1068/250/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="banner-message-content">
    <h3>Content Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae delectus, quod veniam necessitatibus saepe error dicta voluptatem vitae incidunt nulla fugit! Quasi minus libero reiciendis similique cupiditate eum veniam tenetur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:100%;` and `width:fit-content;`

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

SCCS:

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.banner-message {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
     
  .banner-message-media {
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    img {
      height:100%;
      width:fit-content;
    }
  }
  
  .banner-message-content {
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 2;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.banner-message {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.banner-message .banner-message-media {
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.banner-message .banner-message-content {
  padding: 20px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-message">
  <div class="banner-message-media">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1068/250/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="banner-message-content">
    <h3>Content Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae delectus, quod veniam necessitatibus saepe error dicta voluptatem vitae incidunt nulla fugit! Quasi minus libero reiciendis similique cupiditate eum veniam tenetur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit` property in your `.banner-message-media` css class. Like this
`object-fit: fill` or `object-fit: cover`.